# jQuery: addClass to HTML5 DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue today when adding a class to an HTML5 DOM object.  Sorry if this is a newbie question. :P
Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>stackoverflow example</title>
        <style>
        .centercontent {
            width:100%;
            max-width:1080px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <!-- All direct children of BODY should be centered on the page; however, children should not be added to .centercontent -->
            <h1>Site Name</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </section>
        <footer>
            &copy; no one 2012
        </footer>
    </body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.j"></script>
    <script>
        $("body > *").addClass("centercontent");
    </script>
</html>
```

I believe that it is my JS; however, I have never used addClass before. Thank you all very much for your time. :)
Have a good day!

Comment: You are referencing jQuery with a missing trailing s, it is `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.j"` but should be `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: If you'd use your browsers developer tools you might something like `$ is not defined`.

Answer (score 3):

write simply

```
body > * {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1080px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

as a straight CSS rule in the head section:  looking at your example jQuery seems not really necessary for this task.

This selector is also valid in the CSS block and it works fine (not on IE<=6).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` with your jquery. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body > *").addClass("centercontent");
});
```

Also you are missing an s at the end of your script reference

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.j"></script>     // original
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    // fixed
```

Comment: Since the script is at the end of the document, `$(document).ready()` is not needed.

Comment: That did it :D Thanks! Edit: I used the cSS

Comment: @Felix Good point in his case it did not matter! I just find it is a good habit to always do it.